# Is it possible to remove editor from a custom product type?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, editor

I want to remove the editor and set up only the excerpt to a custom product type (WooCommerce) in my theme, is this possible?

This is how i add my custom product type to the WooCommerce product type selector

```
<?php
defined('ABSPATH') || exit;

class Custom_Product_Type(){
    public function __construct() {
        add_filter('product_type_selector', array($this, 'product_type_selector'));
    }

    function product_type_selector($types) {
        $types['custom_product_type'] = 'Custom product type';
        return $types;
    }
}
new Custom_Product_Type();
```

Comment: What's a "custom product type"?

Comment: Product type from WooCommerce, I edited the text to inform that is from WooCommerce

Comment: What, like Simple or Variable?

Comment: Yes, but a custom product type created from another plugin

Comment: how did you registered your custom product type… Could you share some code in your question please? without that your question is just too vague and unclear.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec product type isn't registered, it's just added to 'product_type_selector' filter

Comment: @RodrigoButzke Even if your fake product type is just added to the product selector, you should provide all related code, more context and details. So I suppose you are getting "simple" product behavior for it, didn't you?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I updated the question. Does it help?

Comment: @RodrigoButzke Yes better than before :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured how to hide the editor only when the product type is selected because if i remove the support:

1) The product type is the hidden and then change the product type to another the editor doesn't appear back

2) The product type is not the hidden and then change the product type to hidden the editor dont dissappear

```
function admin_footer() {
    if ( 'product' !== get_post_type() ) :
        return;
    endif;
    ?><script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
            $("#postdivrich").addClass('hide_if_custom_product_type');
            $("#product-type").trigger('change');
        });
    </script><?php
}
add_action( 'admin_footer', array($this, 'admin_footer'));
```

This way, every time it selects or deselects the product type, it will hide or show using WooCommerce methods

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can disable the default editor by removing **'editor'** from the supports attribute array for register_post_type( 'product', $args )

```
'supports'  => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'custom-fields' ),
```

Change this to somthing like this

```
'supports'  => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'custom-fields' ),
```

You can read wordpress function reference for [register_post_type](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) to learn more about custom post type arguments.

**Update:**

**Method 1:**

To change register_post_type args via "**register_post_type_args**" filter hook.

```
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'product_support_args', 10, 2 );
function product_support_args( $args, $post_type ){

    $post_ids_array = array(2119, 2050); // Add Your Allowed Post IDs Here

    if ( 'product' === $post_type && is_admin()){

        $post_id = $_GET['post']; // Get Post ID from URL

        // Check if the post ID is whitelisted
        if(in_array($post_id, $post_ids_array)){
            $args['supports'] = array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'custom-fields' ); // Remove Editor from supports args array
        } 

    }

    return $args;

}
```

**Method 2:**

By using **remove_post_type_support()** function. You can pass allowed post ids array in the same way we did above if required.

```
add_action( 'current_screen', 'remove_editor_support' );
function remove_editor_support() {

    $get_screen = get_current_screen();
    $current_screen = $get_screen->post_type;
    $post_type = 'product'; // change post type here

    if ($current_screen == $post_type ) {   
        remove_post_type_support( $current_screen, 'editor' ); // remove editor from support argument
    }   

}
```

Comment: But this will change for all products, no?

Comment: Yes, It will for all posts. If you want to do this for particular posts, You can pass additional condition checks.

Comment: Conditional checks for product type? How?

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: I didn't know about this filter, now instead of veryfing IDs, just need to verify the product type, and all good

Comment: Ids check will be useful if you want to apply this filter on particular products, otherwise $post_type == 'product' will apply this filter to all products of custom post type 'product', even if it is registered by any third-party plugin.

Comment: Oh, it didn't work. The $post_id is allways empty because $post is allways null...

Comment: You can try with $post_id = get_queried_object_id();

Comment: I have updated my answer, both methods are tested.

Comment: Yes, they work. But i can't use the function get_product_type to check the type...

Comment: To use get_product_type() function you need to pass 'product id' as parameter. So technically you can not use this function while adding/creating a new post.  While editing a post you can use $product_id = $_GET['post']; method to get post id and then pass it to get_product_type($product_id)

Comment: I tried to $product_id = $_GET['post'];get_product_type($product_id) and it says the function dont exists, probabilly the hooks are before loading wc funcitons

Comment: I figured how to hide it by using the wc tab classes "hide_if", check my answer